# React Native: How to inline a textInput with a button?

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am creating a chatbot ui in ReactNative
How can I implement an inline textinput with button ?

```
<View>
 <Textinput />
 <Button>Press</Button>
</View>
```

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html

Answer (score 13):

To organize components horizontally you need to use [flexDirection](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html#flex-direction). Default flexDirection is set to `column`.

```
<View style={{ flexDirection:'row' }}>
  <Textinput />
  <Button>Press</Button>
</View>
```